# How to iterate through text formats in VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word, formatting

I'd like to change some formatting properties in a Word file, thus I need to loop through all the [text runs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/working-with-runs) in that file and change their properties with VBA. However I can't find anyway to do that. I checked [Working with Word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/miscellaneous/concepts-word-vba-reference) and found out that we can iterate over [Words, Characters, Sentences, Paragraphs, Sections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/customizing-word/modifying-a-portion-of-a-document) but nothing else. I tried [moving the range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.move) manually to the next formatting like this but it doesn't work

```
Dim nextRange As Range
ActiveDocument.Range.Move Unit:=wdCharacterFormatting, count:=0
Do
    nextRange = ActiveDocument.Range.Next(Unit:=wdCharacterFormatting)
Loop Until IsNull(nextRange)
```

It says *Object variable or With block variable not set* but the variable was already set

Comment: If the error is `Object variable or With block variable not set` then the variable is not set, despite your indication to the contrary...

Comment: @Martin but what variable? `ActiveDocument.Range.Move` can be called successfully so none of them is null, so `ActiveDocument.Range.Next` should be callable

Comment: I can't test so am not sure, but I'd guess that `Loop Until nextRange = 0` is causing the error.  Debug the error maybe - which line does it occur on?

Comment: @Martin I already debugged before asking this. It throws the error right in the first loop

Comment: On this line: `nextRange = ActiveDocument.Range.Next(Unit:=wdCharacterFormatting)`?

Comment: @Martin yes. There's currently only that single line in the loop

Comment: It would help if you said what it is you're trying to do. «I'd like to change some formatting properties in a Word file, thus I need to loop through all the text runs in that file and change their properties with VBA» is so vague as to be meaningless, since the code you posted does nothing.

Comment: Long-term, you should switch to using styles for your formatting. It makes for much less complex document files.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon I know. But many people are just completely unaware of formatting features. You know many people still align by long pressing the space bar 

Comment: I am aware that many (most?) users are unaware of how styles work. Many people think Covid is a hoax. I still wear a mask. Here is my writing about how important styles are in using Word. http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#Overview

Answer (score 0):

After managing to understand the error that was occuring, there may be three issues.

**1. Handling the `Move` result**

There is no check to ensure the `Move` works:

```
ActiveDocument.Range.Move Unit:=wdCharacterFormatting, count:=0
```

This will return 0 if the move wasn't successful.  The result should be captured and verified:

```
Dim result As Long
result = ActiveDocument.Range.Move(Unit:=wdCharacterFormatting, Count:=0)
If (result > 0) Then
    ...
End If
```

**2. `nextRange` Assignment**

`nextRange` is currently being assigned incorrectly.  The `nextRange` needs to be set using the `Set` keyword:

```
Set nextRange = ActiveDocument.Range.Next(Unit:=wdCharacterFormatting)
```

**3. Loop exit check**

When there is no result from `Range.Next`, `nextRange` will then be set to `Nothing`, which should be used in the `Loop` statement to determine when to stop the loop:

```
Do
    Set nextRange = ActiveDocument.Range.Next(Unit:=wdCharacterFormatting)
Loop Until nextRange Is Nothing
```

**Full code**

The full code then becomes:

```
Dim nextRange As Range
Dim result As Long

result = ActiveDocument.Range.Move(Unit:=wdCharacterFormatting, Count:=0)
If (result > 0) Then
    Do
        Set nextRange = ActiveDocument.Range.Next(Unit:=wdCharacterFormatting)
    Loop Until nextRange Is Nothing
End If
```

Comment: unfortunately the `Range.Move` was unsuccessful. And if I don't move then `Range.Next` also returns Nothing

Answer (score 0):

This might help your understanding

```
    Dim myRange As Word.Range
    
    Set myRange = ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory)
    myRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
    
    Do
        
        DoEvents
        myRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        myRange = myRange.Next(Unit:=wdCharacterFormatting)
        If myRange Is Nothing Then Exit Do
        
        Dim myWorkingRange As Word.Range
        Set myWorkingRange = myRange.Duplicate
        
        ' do stuff with my working range
        
    Loop
```

' Update 27 Nov 2020

corrected unit:=wdFormatting to unit:=wdCharacterFormatting

Stepping through the code above using judiciously inserted myrange.select statements will show that moving the range based on wdCharacterFormatting does not work as expected.  It is necessary to modify the code to that below to reliably evaluate every run range in the document.  Some additional code will be needed if it is desired to not process paragraph markers in the same way as text.  In the code below I've left the select statements I used to check the correct functioning of the code.  These can be removed when you understand what is happening as you move through the document.

The caveat of the code below is that it highlights runs of text with the same character formatting.  Whether this constitutes a change will require additional testing against the 'normal or desired'  formatting by the programmer.

```
    Dim myRange As Word.Range
    Set myRange = ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory)
    myRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
    
    Do
        DoEvents
        
        myRange.Select
        myRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        myRange.Select
        myRange.MoveEnd unit:=wdCharacterFormatting
        myRange.Select
        
        Dim myWorkingRange As Word.Range
        Set myWorkingRange = myRange.Duplicate
        ' do stuff with my working range
        myWorkingRange.Font.ColorIndex = wdBrightGreen
        
        myRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
     ' adjust for formatting holders at end of document
     Loop Until myRange.End = ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory).End - 1
`
```

Comment: I get "Bad parameter" on the first time running `myRange = myRange.Next(Unit:=wdformatting)`

Comment: my bad.  It should be unit:=wdcharacterformatting.  But the code above will not do what you are expecting due to the vagaries of word.  I'll update my answer later today with a more correct solution.